# Vuex & VueJS (Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

I'm trying to create a **listenAuth** function that watches "**onAuthStateChanged**" in **firebase** to notify the **vuex store** when a user has logged in or out. As far as I can tell, I'm only modifying state.authData using the mutation handler, unless I'm missing something?

**I'm getting the error:**

```
[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

**Here's my App.vue javascript (from my component)**

```
<script>
// import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import * as actions from './vuex/actions'
import store from './vuex/store'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

export default {
  store,
  ready: function () {
    this.listenAuth()
  },
  vuex: {
    actions,
    getters: {
      authData: state => state.authData,
      user: state => state.user
    }
  },
  components: {
    // Navigation
  },
  watch: {
    authData (val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.redirectLogin
        this.$route.router.go('/login')
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    listenAuth: function () {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authData) => {
        this.changeAuth(authData)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here's my action (changeAuth) function**

```
export const changeAuth = ({ dispatch, state }, authData) => {
  dispatch(types.AUTH_CHANGED, authData)
}
```

**Here's my store (the parts that matter)**

```
const mutations = {
  AUTH_CHANGED (state, authData) {
    state.authData = authData
  }
}

const state = {
  authData: {}
}
```

Comment: You may want to upgrade to Vuex 2.0

Answer (score 19):

I also came across this issue. My store:

```
  state: {
    items: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SetItems (state, payload) {
      // Warning
      state.items = payload.items
    }
  },
  actions: {
    FetchItems ({commit, state}, payload) {
      api.getItemsData(payload.sheetID)
        .then(items => commit('SetItems', {items}))
    }
  }
```

Fixed it by replace `state.items = payload.items` with:

```
state.items = payload.items.slice()
```

> **The reason is that arrays are stored as references in Javascript and `payload.items` is likely to be changed outside Vuex. So we should
>   just use a fresh copy of `payload.items` instead.**

For state objects, use:

```
state.someObj = Object.assign({}, payload.someObj)
```

And don't use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj))` as it's much slower.

Answer (score 11):

After struggling with the same problem, I found that the error only happens when we try to store the auth/user data in the Vuex state.

Changing from...

```
const mutations = {
  AUTH_CHANGED (state, authData) {
    state.authData = authData
  }
}
```

...to...

```
const mutations = {
  AUTH_CHANGED (state, authData) {
    state.authData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authData))
  }
}
```

would solve your case.

Comment: Use `state.authData = Object.assign({}, authData)` instead. Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: For some reason `Object.assign({}, authData)` doens't work, but `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authData))`does.

Comment: the reason `Object.assign` doesn't work sometimes is because it doesn't perform a deep copy, as described in the doc `"For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value."` . for deep clone, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` is better, even if it will certainly be slower

Comment: upvoted for the alternative suggested, works for my auth as well

Comment: I'd like to ask why does this solution work since there is no explanation.

Comment: @Shulz That's a good question. It's been 4 years since I wrote this answer and I don't have any idea why it works anymore. Self-reminder: next time, actually explain stuff instead of just providing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and I used lodash to clone data

```
state.someStatehere = $lodash.cloneDeep(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

So from many answers we can agree on the cause: the object stored in the state is silently modified by something that holds reference to it. And many suggest making a copy of the object.

The other alternative is to empty the state while the object is being modified. This works when for some reason you cannot copy the object.
For example:

```
bla({ state } {}) {
  mutatingMethod(state.xxx);
},
```

If you know `mutatingMethod` is modifying xxx then you can do something like this:

```
bla({ state } {}) {
  let xxx = state.xxx
  commit("SET_XXX", null)
  mutatingMethod(xxx);
  commit("SET_XXX", xxx)
},
```

Answer (score -1):

For anybody who's also struggling with this, this is another way to fix it (what actually worked for me):

```
auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      commit(MUTATION_TYPES.SET_USER, { ...user.toJSON() });
    }
  })
```